# Error CodeIgniter: too many connection database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem with my code, I get the error:

> too many connection database.

This is my controller

```
class Api extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Application_model', '', TRUE);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "Access Denied";
    }

      public function application_detail($application_key = null)
    {
        $response['isSuccess'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "data not found";
        if ($application_key != null) {
            $application = $this->Application_model->get_application_detail($application_key);
            if ($application != null) {
                $response['isSuccess'] = true;
                $response['message'] = "data found";
                $response[$application_key] = $application->$application_key;
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    }
```

and this is model:

```
class Application_model extends CI_Model
{
    function get_application_detail($application_key)
    {
        $this->db
            ->select($application_key);
        $this->db->from('application');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
    }

}
```

so how to fix it ?

Comment: what is the `pconnect` value. Have you changed anything. in database.php file

Answer (score 0):

The first link in Google that i found
[Fix many connection error](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-database-connection/)

Did you try it?

**UPDATED:**

Second approach is to change db_driver to more newest

1. make sure to enable *extension=mysqli.so* in php.ini (if not installed, you should additionally install mysqli package for php)
2. change DB driver in Codeigniter to *'dbdriver' => 'mysqli'*

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AmayDiam can you share you config connection DB file?

Comment: $db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'sss',
 'password' => 'ss',
 'database' => 'ssss',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);